# How can I prevent the death of this major NPC at the end of the Battle of Kaer Morhen?

Tags: the-witcher-3

How can I prevent

> Vesemir

from dying at the end of 'The Battle of Kaer Morhen'?

What kind of choices do I have to make in the preparation of this battle to let this person survive?

Comment: Two things: You can use >! to hide text behind spoiler text, and please don't sacrifice the quality of your title to avoid spoilers. I've modified you title to improve it's quality, but please feel free to remove the spoiler if you can come up with  agood title which avoid it. Just remember: A quality title is more important than a spoiler free one.

Comment: I believe the current version of the title is a good compromise. Assuming no other major NPCs can die at that point, it is fairly specific, and searching for "Vesemir death Kaer Morhen" should still work. That said, I'd definitely put the spoiler in the title if the game was older as the chances of accidentally spoiling someone decrease with age.

Comment: Thank you, Wipqozn and MrLemon for your edits. Its great to have an example with >! for future spoiler questions. @MrLemon : Do you say if this question would be for the first 'Witcher' (2007), you would write 'Vesemir' instead of 'this major NPC' in the title? Sorry, I'm not sure what you exactly mean.

Comment: @PeterCo yes, basically. At some point (in time), the chances of spoiling anyone who cares are so small that the value of a good title outweighs avoiding spoilers. But since right now, there are many people who might want to play the game but haven't played yet (for various reasons), we should take care to avoid spoilers in the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. His death is a major narrative event that needs to happen for the story. Sorry for your loss.